# mod rewrite with 2 parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just started to learn about mod rewrite process. Now, I got some problems about mod rewrite using 2 parameters like the following statements:

**Normal URL format**

```
domain.com/index.php?p=portfolio&c=web-application
```

**Target URL format**

```
domain.com/portfolio/web-application
```

**Currently Rewrite Rule**

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z-0-9]+)/?$    ?p=$1&c=$2  [L]
```

**Snapshot of problem**
[Snapshot http://www.iamnbty.com/mod-rewrite-problem.PNG](http://www.iamnbty.com/mod-rewrite-problem.PNG)

**Target**

```
www.iamnbty.com/mod-rewrite-target.PNG
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([\S-]+)/([\S-]+)/?$   ?p=$1&c=$2 [L]
```

Comment: This rule is working, but all style after rendered has been gone. It's just like a simple HTML. T_T

Target
http://www.iamnbty.com/mod-rewrite-target.PNG

Problem
http://www.iamnbty.com/mod-rewrite-problem.PNG

Comment: your style should be something that matches with pattern. otherwise they should be loaded correctly.

Comment: I'm just uploaded my project to www.iamnbty.com/portfolio
You can trying to browse to www.iamnbty.com/portfolio/web-application

Comment: `404 Not Found`: you have used relative URL for css(`css/iamnbty-carousel-slider.css`). use absolute or use `/css/iamnbty-carousel-slider.css`

Comment: [Your site](http://up.vatandownload.com/images/iyej47icnl9ugur6lp2y.png) using relative to root directory path.

Comment: I'm changed all links in my website to ABSOLUTE URLs. Thanks ^__^